# Graph property intuition

Tags: graph-theory, intuition, visualization

I was showing some basic graph property and though I could formally prove it, I can't wrap my head around the intuition of why this property holds. The property is the following:

Let $G$ be a graph of $m$ edges. Show that for every $d \in \mathbb N$, if $m < \dfrac{d \times (d+1)}{2}$, then there is a node $v$ such that $d(v) < d$, where $d(v)$ is the degree of the node $v$.

My proof is by contradiction using the properties that the degree of every node is bounded by (cardinal of G) - 1 and by the equality $2m = \sum_{v \in G} d(v)$.

Any explanation or visual ideas on why this property is indeed true would by greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this is what you are looking for.  Let $v$ be a vertex of $G$.  If $v$ has degree less than $d$, then we are done.  If not, then $v$ has at least $d$ neighboring vertices, say, $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_k$ with $k\geq d$.  Now, the total number of edges of the vertex-induced subgraph with vertices $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_k$ and all their neighbors is at least
$$\frac{1}{2}\,\left(k+\sum_{i=1}^k\,\deg(v_i)\right)\,.$$
(Here is probably a possible visual idea.  Well, try to imagine what this subgraph look like and why the expression above is a lower bound on the number of edges in this subgraph.)

By the assumption that there are less than $\dfrac{d(d+1)}{2}$ edges in $G$, we get
$$\frac{1}{2}\,\left(k+\sum_{i=1}^k\,\deg(v_i)\right)<\frac{d(d+1)}{2}\,.$$
Thus,
$$\frac{1}{k}\,\sum_{i=1}^k\,\deg(v_i)<\frac{d(d+1)}{k}-1\leq d\,.$$
By the Pigeonhole Principle, $\deg(v_j)<d$ for some $j\in\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$.